# How should audio be pre-processed for classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, classification

I am currently developing an audio classifier with the Python API of TensorFlow, using the UrbanSound8K dataset and trying to distinguish between 10 mutually exclusive classes.

The audio files are 4 seconds long and contain 176400 data points which results in serious memory issues. How should the audio be pre-processed to reduce memory usage?

And how can more useful features be extracted from the audio (using convolution and pooling)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I personally prefer spectrograms as input for neural nets when it comes to sound classification. This way, raw audio data is transformed into an image representation and you can treat it like a basic image classification task.

There are a number of ways to choose from, here is what I usually do using scipy, [python_speech_features](https://github.com/jameslyons/python_speech_features) and [pydub](https://github.com/jiaaro/pydub):

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile as wave
import python_speech_features as psf
from pydub import AudioSegment

#your sound file
filepath = 'my-sound.wav'

def convert(path):

    #open file (supports all ffmpeg supported filetypes) 
    audio = AudioSegment.from_file(path, path.split('.')[-1].lower())

    #set to mono
    audio = audio.set_channels(1)

    #set to 44.1 KHz
    audio = audio.set_frame_rate(44100)

    #save as wav
    audio.export(path, format="wav")

def getSpectrogram(path, winlen=0.025, winstep=0.01, NFFT=512):

    #open wav file
    (rate,sig) = wave.read(path)

    #get frames
    winfunc=lambda x:np.ones((x,))
    frames = psf.sigproc.framesig(sig, winlen*rate, winstep*rate, winfunc)

    #Magnitude Spectrogram
    magspec = np.rot90(psf.sigproc.magspec(frames, NFFT))

    #noise reduction (mean substract)
    magspec -= magspec.mean(axis=0)

    #normalize values between 0 and 1
    magspec -= magspec.min(axis=0)
    magspec /= magspec.max(axis=0)

    #show spec dimensions
    print magspec.shape    

    return magspec

#convert file if you need to
convert(filepath)

#get spectrogram
spec = getSpectrogram(filepath)
```

First, you need to standardize your audio files in terms of sample rate and channels. You can do that (and more) with the excellent **pydub** package.

After that, you need to transform your audio signal into an image with FFT. You can do that with **scipy.io.wavefile** and the sigproc modul of **python_speech_features**. I like the magnitude spectrogram, rotate it 90 degrees, normalize it and use the resulting NumPy array as input for my convnets. You can change the spatial dimensions of the spectrogram by adjusting the values of ***winstep*** and ***NFFT*** to fit your input size.

There might be easier ways to do all that; I achieved good overall classification results using the code above.

Comment: why should the spectrogram be rotated by 90 degrees?

Comment: It does not matter at all for the convnet input, only for viewing and understanding what it depicts (spectrograms usually have time as x-axis). You can simply ignore the 90 degree rotation if you are not going to visualize the spectrogram.

Comment: You should also note that mean(axis=0) is the mean only for columns. Mean substraction for the entire spectrogram needs axis=None (which is the default).

Comment: so, what are the effective differences between subtracting mean(axis=0) and mean(axis=None)?

Comment: The results are quite different, but in the end it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Substracting the mean of each column (axis=0) gives you a spectrogram where the noise is suppressed when there is a distinct signal; which is good for signal/noise separation. Substracting the mean of the entire spectrogram (axis=None) results in a signal-only spectrogram. (The same applies for the min/max-normalization)